# error after .aar integration

Tags: build, codenameone, aar

I was using .andlib upto now and now as CN1 has changed default to Gradle so in accordance to that I generated .aar of my native android code.

But when I had sent a build,

1) first I got duplicate permission error for Internet connection.

then I removed Internet Connection from my android project and it resolve error but

2) second time I got

`Unknown source file : /tmp/build5662507870470893154xxx/StockTake/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/drawable-mdpi/icon.png: error: Duplicate file.
Unknown source file : /tmp/build5662507870470893154xxx/StockTake/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/drawable-mdpi-v4/icon.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.`

[Full build error is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ivvps8hpgxvg69/f4fc07dc-9ca5-4ded-8f38-0082ac0cee14-1451521035136-error.txt?dl=0)

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a file named `icon.png` in one of your native directories or cn1libs?

This could collide with the icon we set into place.

Comment: Even after above changes, in future if someone stuck, with
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load YourLibrary from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/XYZ.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/XYZ/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null`

Then you have to add in build.gradle following lines

`android {


    sourceSets {


        main {


            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']


        }


   }


}`



I had .so files in libs directory so MUST have to add them in gradle file then only it will work.
Cheers.